# Gcc and g++ different on write()

Tags: c

```
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#define BUFSIZE 1024

main()
{
     char buf[BUFSIZE];
     int n;
     while((n=read(0,buf,BUFSIZE))>0)
         write(1,buf,n);
     return 0;
}
```

When I compile this by using gcc, it is fine.
But use g++ I got :

```
inandout.c:7:32: error: ‘read’ was not declared in this scope
     while((n=read(0,buf,BUFSIZE))>0)
                                ^
inandout.c:8:22: error: ‘write’ was not declared in this scope
         write(1,buf,n);
                      ^
```

Why is that?

Comment: read and write are in unistd.h, you got lucky in C or there is some kind of corner that I don't know about.

Comment: Try `#include <unistd.h>`

Comment: Because C and C++ are different languages …. These are not the only things g++ should complain about (hint: always compile using `-pedantic`).

Comment: @KonradRudolph: and `-Wall`, `-Wextra`, `-Wshadow` and some other options :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is because gcc is a C compiler, g++ is a C++ compiler, and [C and C++ are different languages](http://741mhz.com/c-vs-cxx/).

If you want to compiler that source code as C++ program, you must change it to become C++. For example, there are no implicit function declarations in C++, so you must include `unistd.h` for `read()` and `write()` declarations. You also don't need `syscall.h` header.

Also, it is only that simple because you have a simple code snippet. Porting C code to C++ could be a nightmare as there are ~ 50 differences and in some cases code compiles well in both cases, but behaves differently.

P.S.: And instead of defining weird BUFSIZE yourself, consider using standard [`BUFSIZ`](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Controlling-Buffering.html) :)

Answer (score 2):

You Just need to add  `include <unistd.h>`

Answer (score 1):

C defaults functions that do not have a prototype to a function that returns an int - but you should have got warnings for that (did you use `-Wall`?).

C++ doesn't allow that, you need to include the correct header file, `unistd.h`, which you should also do in C.

Comment: May as well throw in `-Wextra` too.

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded to gcc 4.8.5. In version 4.7 the compiler stopped including unistd.h in a number of include files. This is why older gcc compiler versions worked without including unistd.h.

https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.7/porting_to.html 
"C++ language issues
Header dependency changes
Many of the standard C++ library include files have been edited to no longer include unistd.h to remove namespace pollution. "

In my case I got ::write has not been declared when I included stdio.h, but my previous gcc version 4.4 compiled fine.  This is a useful command to see what paths are being searched by the preprocessor: g++ -H test.cpp